# The space of $S^1/S^1$, the space of a single point, and their first homotopy group

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I read from the book *Soft matter physics* by Kleman that the space $R$ of a point is $0$ and its first homotopy group $\pi_1(0)=0$. This causes some confusion to my understanding.

1. Why the space of a single point is $0$ rather than $1$? I consider there is still one element in the space.
2. Is the space of $S^1/S^1$ a single point? If so, is $S^1/S^1 = 1$ or $0$?
3. Is $\pi_1(0) = 0$?

I am learning some basic topology at the same time (from the physics side of view), but I still only know a few of them. Can any give me some hints? Any hits are warmly welcome.

Comment: I've completed quite a few topology courses, and it's the first time I've heard about $0$ denoting the one point space. It's usually been denoted by $\{*\}$. That $\pi_1(\{*\})=0$ is trivial, as there is only one map from circle to one point (the constant one). Likewise, $S^1/S^1$ is a single point: if you identify all points in $S^1$ which are in $S^1$, there's not much left, is there?

Comment: @tomasz: “0” might legitimately denote the trivial group in algebraic geometry and related domains, because it is the zero object in the category of groups and many its important subcategories: abelian groups, *R*-modules, vector spaces…. Of course, this 0 a.k.a. {0} is a singleton space (from topological point of view) and one can consider both as the same thing.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: but it is certainly *not* a zero object in the category of topological spaces. I suppose it makes some sense if we interpret it in the category of *pointed* topological spaces (where $\{*\}$ is the zero object), which makes sense in context of algebraic topology, more so than referring to algebraic geometry.

Comment: @tomasz: {∗} is zero object of the category of connected non-empty topological spaces with homotopy classes of maps as morphisms. Pointed topological spaces are less relevant.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: The homotopy groups are usually (or at least were to me) introduced for pointed topological spaces. I guess they might as well be introduced for topological spaces modulo homotopy class with a distinguished arc component, or something of the sort, but I would hardly think that pointed space are irrelevant with respect to algebraic topology. The latter setting may be more natural in many ways, but its of dubious pedagogical value to someone just learning the basics of topology, while the concept of a pointed topological space is relatively simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, most of these questions are pretty much about notation, which I love/hate getting in to discussions about.  Having said that, I've rarely seen the space of a point denoted by a numeral, but when I have it's been $1$.  Somewhat less rarely, I've seen the group with one element denoted by a numeral, and almost always as $1$, unless it's clear the group is abelian.  So, if we denote both as $1$, then I could see writing $\pi_1(1)=1$, but that looks completely alien to me.

To answer the more serious questions in your post, yes $S^1/S^1$ is a one point space, and yes the fundamental group of a point is the trivial group of one element.  These should be obvious from the definitions, so I think your understanding of quotient spaces and fundamental groups is pretty fuzzy, not helped by reading from a book using ( to me ) unusual notation.

You can think of the quotient $X/Y$ as formed by gluing all the points of $Y$ to one point.  So, in this case, it should be obvious that $S^1/S^1$ is a single point.

$\pi_1$ of a space is the collection of continuous maps from $S^1$ to that space, with some maps identified with each other ( and more structure that makes it a group,  etc. ).  In the case of a one point space, there is only one map from $S^1$ to that space, so regardless of the rest of the definition of $\pi_1$, it only has one element, so yes, $\pi_1$ of a one point space is the one element group.